# How to create a utils library in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular. Sorry for the basic question but I couldn't find info about how to write a library in Angular the proper way.

The reason is to benefit from Angular modules as well as testability/mocks.

### The library

I am transferring my code to Angular but a big part of my code is written based on a library that I've developed over a couple of months. Imagine something like *underscore*.

So my initial thought was to wrap it in an angular module like:

```
angular.module('mylib', [])
       .factory('map', map)
       .factory('reduce', reduce)
       .factory('find', find);

function map (...
```

Each factory function is testable and stuff. And then use it like:

```
angular.module('app', ['mylib'])
       .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'map', MainCtrl]);

function MainCtrl($scope, map) {
    ... do stuff with map ...
```

This is fine for a couple of functions I guess but my library has over 20 functions and it's just too much boilerplate to define every one of them as a factory and then inject them into my controller.

### Second solution

Another way is to have just one factory that returns an object. Kinda like this:

```
angular.module('mylib', [])
       .factory('mylib', mylib)

function mylib () {
  var exports = {};

  exports.map = function (...
  exports.reduce = function (...
  exports.find = function (...

  return exports;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['mylib'])
       .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'mylib', MainCtrl]);

function MainCtrl($scope, mylib) {
    ... do stuff with mylib.map ...
```

### But...

Is this a good approach? What would a good way to write a utility library in Angular and use it? Readability and maintainability are important but I prefer not to have so much boilerplate code.

Comment: I have separate factory for each function and one factory which injects and returns instances of all other factories.

Comment: Is your library completely independent of Angular currently? Does it really *need* to depend on Angular? If your library just contains utility functions as generic as `map` or `reduce` I don't see the benefit in making it depend on Angular in the first place.

Comment: Yes it is independent of Angular. Think *underscorejs* but for converting numerical values from different unit systems.

Comment: If it is a pure javascript utils library similar to underscore, I'd argue angular's dependency injection is unnecessary (it mostly facilitates mocking and you almost never need to mock generic libraries). I'd use CommonJS and npm, but bower/globals is also OK. Don't couple to angular unless the code is angular-specific.

Comment: It's a fair argument, but I kinda like the testability feature of angular modules. Besides I'd like the whole code to be modular using angular module system.

Answer (score 5):

If your library functions are as generic as your example, I wouldn't try to define them as Angular modules in the first place. Write a plain JS library. That will result in less useless boilerplate, and as a bonus your library will also be usable in non-Angular apps. Angular plays along nicely with libraries that are unaware of it, for example by not requiring data objects to implement anything extra (think `ko.observable`, Backbone `Model`, etc) to be usable with data binding.

Being an Angular module is not a requirement for testability. The only thing I can think of that Angular could do to improve testability in a generic utility library is the dependency injection (e.g. injecting a mock service for "current time" into a time library for deterministic results). If you don't need any of that, take the past of least complication and just write a plain JS library.

If wrapping the library in an Angular module is an absolute requirement (for instance to not pollute the global namespace with a short namespace for it), I would still write the library in plain JS, put it into a more complicated namespace, and then alias it with an Angular module.

lib/handy-utilities-1.0.js

```
// Or any other descriptive namespace
var handyUtilities = {
    map: function() { ... }
};
```

app/util.js

```
angular.module("handyUtilities", []).constant("util", handyUtilities);
```